# Software updater not working

Tags: apt, updates, software-center

The following error occurred while opening software updater/Ubuntu software center/sypnatic package manager/software sources.

```
E:Encountered a section with no Package: header, 
E:Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists /ppa.launchpad.net_atareao_atareao_ubuntu_dists_quantal_main_i18n_Translation-en, 
E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

How to solve this problem?. Any help please.

Answer (score 1):

After digging many sites now I have solved the problem with the following commands in terminal. Hope this may help someone who is having the same error message.

```
1. sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
2. sudo apt-get update
3. sudo apt-get upgrade
```